# Mathematica 12 default graphic opacity is 0, i.e. invisible

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1**

---

I just upgraded to Mathematica 12 and am trying to draw a line in a graphic and am finding that the default opacity for a new notebook is 0, making them invisible.  I can correct this for lines but can't for text which just draws as pink background without any letters.  Is this a known bug?

Didn't have the problem in 11.3, downgrade?
[image]

Here's my default Drawing Tools:

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to change the font opacity in the "Text" section of the Drawing Tools palette.

Comment: I'm curious, if you have a notebook with a drawn graphic from V11.3 and open it in V12, are lines/text visible if you draw new ones?

Comment: I don't see any unexpected behavior when drawing a line in a graphic. Does it happen in a new notebook if you as the first thing press Format -> Stylesheet -> Default?

Comment: Format > Stylesheet > Default was already selected.  All my startup opacities are 0.

Comment: Opening an 11.3 notebook with a graphic has the same problem, opacities are default to 0 and require changing every time.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting a new question. See the tag description for why.

Comment: I've downgraded to 11.3 which still works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue so I contact Wolfram Customer Office. It is said that this mistake will be solved soon.

Comment: Future reader, before you flag or downvote, the question was "Is this a known bug?" and this post answers it well, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

### This is a bug, but I think there is a fix

I've run into this bug myself. Some features of the text are just hard to change for some reason: for example, I have difficulty changing the color of the text through the "Drawing Tools" (you can change it through the format menu much more easily).

But when it comes to the text being invisible, I think I've found a fix. **That problem seems to go away if you close all other Mathematica windows** (meaning any other "notebooks" you have open). **Once you've done that, you should be able to change the opacity of the text with the slider**, and make it visible again. Keep in mind, changing the opacity will only make all your *subsequent* text visible. Your previous text will still be transparent, and should probably be deleted.