# drawing tools don't work

Tags: drawing

I'm using Mathematica version 12.0 and just starting using the drawing tools.  Everything seemed to be working well until it didn't.  Mathematica crashed and when I restarted, I no longer could see lines and a little orange box appear. I suspect the thickness of the lines is basically zero but I don't know how to fix it.  The opacity is set to 1 everywhere and all the thickness settings are nonzero.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Mathematica 12 default graphic opacity is 0, i.e. invisible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195351/mathematica-12-default-graphic-opacity-is-0-i-e-invisible)

Comment: This is a very annoying bug in 12.0. Please double-check that all relevant opacities are really 1 (there are multiple), colours are not white, thicknesses are not zero, and try drawing *after* all these were verified. Note that there are different settings for different elements (fill, stroke, etc.)